# Resources not getting released in java

Tags: java, resources

So, I have a function that reads file data, in this case image size. But after it's done it doesn't seem to properly release the files. I can't move those files afterwards. If I don't call this function everything works, but if I do I always get "file in use.. blah blah blah"

```
private void setMoveType() {
    ImageInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new FileInputStream(file.toString()));
        try {
            final Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(in);
            if(readers.hasNext()) {
                ImageReader reader = readers.next();
                try {
                    reader.setInput(in);
                    try {
                        moveType = Helper.getMoveType(new Dimension(reader.getWidth(0), reader.getHeight(0)));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
                        return;
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("ReaderException: " + e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    reader.dispose();
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("MoveTypeSetException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.print("IOException: failure while creating image input stream");
        System.err.println(" -> createImageInputStream Error for file: " + file.getFileName());
        return;
    } finally {
        if(in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: The ImageInputStream doesn't close properly

EDIT2: a FileInputStream wasn't closed

Comment: Use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

Comment: @Tom no luck either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stream should also be closed:

```
new FileInputStream(file.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

Closing the stream when you are done should work (`in.close()`). The operating system prevents the file from being changed, deleted or moved while it is in use. Otherwise, the stream would get messed up. Closing the stream tells the operating system you are no longer using the file.

Comment: well, it doesn't do that for some reason. and after little testing I know for sure it's the ImageInputStream that's not closing properly.

Comment: Did you call `in.close()` at the end of your code? Otherwise the OS can't tell if you are done with the file or not.